# Rstudio diagnostic and data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio, diagnostics

Is there a way to make Rstudio diagnostics aware of data.table syntax?
Currently code that will work with data.table is flagged as problematic by the Rstudio diagnostics

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(var1 = c(1,2), var2 = c(3,4))
dt[,var3:=var1+var2,]

add_f <- function(input_dt) input_dt[,var3:=var1+var2,]

add_f(dt)
```

[image]

edit: added example with function
edit2: added example with brackets for function

Comment: It doesn't show me this after I have run the first two lines. Before you define the data.table, it can't know that `var1` and `var2` have been defined within a data.table.

Comment: This is true. But the problem still occurs if you use data.table syntax within a function. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: `input_dt` doesn't necessarily contain `var1` and `var2`. The function is generic, so the warning in line 6 is correct. You only tell in line 10 that you intend to use a `data.table` containing `var1`& `var2`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you had missed out the curly brackets `{}` in `function`

paste the below in your RStudio and check. Mine does not flag any error

```
# dummy df
df <- data.table(var1 = c(1,2)
                 , var2 = c(3,4)
                 ); df

# function
add_f <- function(input_dt)
{
  input_dt[, var3 := var1 + var2]
}
```

Comment: For me the variables are still marked. Even if I use brackets. I checked all boxes but the "Provide R Style ..." and "... for Java Script ..." ones.